PHP intelephense shows error : Undefined method 'toArray' with Laminas
When using PHP intelephense in VS Code for my laminas project, it is showing error,
Undefined method 'toArray'

My code looks as below,
<?php

namespace Something\Model;

use Laminas\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Laminas\Db\Sql\Select;

use Infrastructure\Abstraction\AbstractTableGateway;

class SomethingModel extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table = 'some_table';

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return $this->select(function (Select $select) use () {
            $select->columns(['something']);
        })->toArray();
    }
}

I was able eliminate this error by changing the code as follows,
/** @var \Laminas\Db\ResultSet\AbstractResultSet $select **/
$select = $this->select(function (Select $select) use () {
    $select->columns(['something']);
});
return $select->toArray();

But i don't want it to assign to any variable. So is there any alternative way to remove the error?

You need to wrap it into parenthesis. But there is nothing against putting it into a variable. It even helps better debugging. The extra memory needed for the reference is negligible and will be catched by the garbage collector.
class Any {
    public function call()
    {
        echo 'Any';
    }
}

$any = new Any();
$any->call();

// can be simplified to:

(new Any())->call();

Update
Digging around, I did not find any word that Intelephense does currently support fluent interfaces. Testing that with PHPStorm does not make any problem.

Thank you. But i am extending AbstractTableGateway and calling it with $this. I can't do this right? ($this->any())->toArray();

Yes, you could. If $this->any() returns an instance with the toArray method.

Sadly, even with bracket it is showing the same error.

Can you please edit the code, and add an update section with the current code? (don't change the question code itself). One additional important question: Does PHP complain about the error or just VScode? Maybe it is just the static analyzer being uncapable of parsing that.

PHP didn't complain. Only VS Code showing the error. But when we see that in the code editor it is annoying.

$this->update(), $this->insert and $this->select works fine. But, when adding ->toArray() with select it is showing the error

Digging around, I did not find any word that Intelephense does suppert fluent interfaces. Testing that with PHPStorm does not make any problem.

Maybe it is a VS Code specific issue.

I would say a missing feature.
